# Compare and swap library?

Tags: c++

What is the best cross platform library to use for atomic compare and swap operations in c++?

...Or at least for amd64 on Linux and Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the compiler compatibility you need.

If you are using GCC on both platforms, you can just use GCC's atomic primitives, as they are tied to the hardware architecture, not the OS platform.

Otherwise, as PeterK suggested, look at Boost.  There is a [Boost.Atomic](http://www.chaoticmind.net/~hcb/projects/boost.atomic/doc/index.html) candidate library; I don't know what its status on being incorporated is.

Comment: I am using __sync_val_compare_and_swap now. I just assumed that this relatively common functionality would have a widely used standard library for it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [boost](http://www.boost.org). It offers a lot of support for atomic operations.

Comment: Probably my own blindness, but I checked boost and I couldn't support for a CAS operation that would work on 64 bit datatypes. Any chance you can show me what you mean?

Comment: @peter: Boost is woefully lacking in proper support for races. Before using Boost in production, I strongly encourage an audit of the code. You will be surprised what you find.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to boost is [TBB](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) (Threading Building Blocks). It is not a large scale lib like boost and focuses on parallel programming.

Answer (score 0):

C++0X will [finally] be addressing the issue. For GCC, see http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/ExecutiveSummary and http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Atomic/GCCMM/DataRaces.